# How can I add a triangular shape with the thickness of my loop cuts?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to make a simple shape but can't seem to do it right.

It's basically a right-angle shape with edges. Hard to explain, here are the pics:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaYUc.jpg

This is where I'm stuck:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2raa.jpg

All I need to do now is add in the triangles on the sides with the thickness shown by my loop cuts.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create additional geometry and use *Bridge Edge Loops* to achieve the final result.

1. Bridging won't work from the beginning as there aren't 2 edge loops; however you can split existing faces and bridge the result. For that select edge between faces which form the base for the desired triangles. Press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip it and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel moving. You have 2 edge loops now.
2. Switch to Face Select mode, choose both faces and execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*. Internal faces will be deleted for you.
3. Remove doubles (which were made with that ripped edge) via <kbd>W</kbd> menu. Also in 3D View header find *Select* > *Non-Manifold* operator (switch to Vertice or Edge Select mode to use it). Edge in the corner will be selected, delete it.

   [image: bridging faces image example]

Note that tris may be undesired topology (e.g. if subdividing this surface or adding more loopcuts) so use it if you know this part of model will be mostly flat and not needing further subdividing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following for your workflow:

If you are planning on keeping both your angle, and your stiffeners as one mesh object, then delete your two faces that your triangular stiffener plate will be running over top of first.

To do this go into face mode, select your faces (Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one), <kbd>X</kbd> >> *Only Faces*.

Next go into Edge mode.

Next, select your two outer edges (Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one) and using <kbd>W</kbd> >> <kbd>E</kbd>(*Bridge Edge Loops*).

**NOTE:** Repeat this for both triangle loops that get created.

Next Select your triangle edge loop using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd>.

Next hit <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in the the loop.

[image: BridgeEdgeLoopsAndFill]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out lol extruded a square then selected the bottom corner and pulled it back to where the 3d cursor is in my 2nd pic!